# cp -r does not copy specific folder only its content

Tags: cp

I have a folder structure that is something like this:

```
a/
 |b/
   | f1
   | f2
 |c/
   | f3
   | f4
 |d/
   | f5
   | f6
```

Where `b`, `c`, and `d` can contain main files and sub directories. Then I have a destination folder `e`, where the destination folder `e` exists.
When I run `cp -r a/c e/` or `cp -r a/d e/` `c` and `d` are copied to `e` as I expect, with their internal folder structure.
However, when I run `cp -r a/b e/` the result is not the same.
Only the content of `a/b` is copied but not `b` itself.
It is almost like the command that is run is `cp -r a/b/* e/`

I cannot see anything special about the folder with `ls` or `file`. It has the same rights as `c` and `d` and is shown as directory when I run `file` on it.

Is there a way to debug what is happening?
I first experienced the problem running copy from python using subprocess:

```py
import subprocess
import pathlib

for folder in pathlib.Path("a/").iterdir():
    if folder.is_dir():
        subprocess.run(["cp", "-r", str(folder), "e/"])
```

afterwards I tried to run the command `cp -r a/b e/` from the command line and had the samme issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the machine has a service running that deletes empty folders every X seconds.
Therefore, the copy of `b` happened after `e` had already been deleted.
Resulting in this behavior I described above.